# How can I get the sms body and extract the content from that?

Tags: android, sms, android-broadcast, inbox, android-broadcastreceiver

I tried the following code,

```
       Uri inboxURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");

        // List required columns
        String[] reqCols = new String[] { "_id", "address", "body", "date" };
        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        Long currentDate = cal.getTimeInMillis();
        cal.add(Calendar.HOUR, -1);
        Long lastDate = cal.getTimeInMillis();
        String criteria = "date between '" + lastDate + "' and '" + currentDate + "'";

        Cursor c = cr.query(inboxURI, reqCols, criteria, null, null);
        adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row, c,new String[] { "body", "address", "date" }, new int[] {
                        R.id.lblMsg, R.id.lblNumber, R.id.lblDate });
        lvMsg.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Here i'm getting the SMSes which are received in the past 1 hour.

I want to filter even more by the content so tried the following,

```
String criteria = "(body like '%spent%' or body like '%withdrawn%') " +
                "and date between '" + lastDate + "' and '" + currentDate + "'";
```

Now i'm getting the appropriate SMSes. But i want to get the amount which was spent/withdrawn.
 Eg: My SMS is as follows

```
Rs.350.50 was spent oun your Credit card on XXXXXX at XXXX. Avl bal: Rs.35200.05
```

Here I want to extract `350.50`

So this how i want to take all the amount spent/withdrawn from each SMS.

How can I acheive this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this to get the amount. First get the index of integer from the string like this

```
 String s = new String("xyz123");
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\d+").matcher(s);
matcher.find();
int i = Integer.valueOf(matcher.group());
```

Then after getting the index of first integer you can then run a loop checking if the next character is a digit or not. When you find first non digit character exit the loop. So now you have both start and end index of amount. Now you can easily use **String.substring(int startIndex,int endIndex)** method to find exact amount properly